# Storing password securely nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, passwords, nodemailer

I have an app that sends mail using [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer).

```
transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: "email",
    pass: "what here?"
  }
});
```

I want to keep the app open source, just for the heck of it (along with not wanting a plain text password to exist basically anywhere).

I know of nodemailler-direct, but is there a better option here? I also thought about prompting the server console for password, but that's clunky as well.

Is there a "correct" or standard way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use environment variables:

```
transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: process.env.NODEMAILER_SERVICE,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.NODEMAILER_USER,
    pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASS
  }
});
```

You can set these variables on the server and the application will pick them up. For example:

```
NODEMAILER_SERVICE="Gmail"
```

Comment: On the server, this stays persistently over "app-reboots"?

Comment: Well, it depends on how your environment is set up. App reboots should not be a problem, but you will need to make sure these variables are set after a server reboot.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into env variables further, surprised they weren't more prominent when I was learning the basics.